# Manipulating datasets and Filtering data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to filter a dataset using a value gathered from another dataset.

For example

dataset1

```
Name          Group    Colour    Age   Title   JobRole

John Smith    1        NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN 

John Smith    2        NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN 

John Smith    3        NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN 

James Man     1        NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN   

.....
```

dataset2

```
Name          Colour    Age   Title   JobRole

John Smith    Red       35    Mr      SuperMan

James Man     Orange    21    Mr      SuperMan

.....
```

I would like to take each name in dataset1 and then filter dataset2. End goal being adding all the data into dataset1s NaN values.

Im having trouble with the filtering, I have tried a few methods but all produce an empty dataframe.

Attempt so far..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
groupDf = pd.read_excel("dataset1.xlsx")
newDf = pd.read_excel("dataset2.xlsx")


for name in newDf['Name']:
    filtered_data = groupDf[groupDf.Name == name]
    print(filtered_data)
```

Output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Group]
Index: []
```

Comment: Should the three *John Smith* in **dataset 2** have the same **group** number or should it be 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: different group values you are correct sir (ive omitted some extra colomns to simplify the dataset)

Comment: @iNoob - In `Group` column in `df2` are `NaN`s only?